# Removing dotted lines around widget

Tags: html, css, wordpress

After putting an html text widget into my page primary sidebar, dotted lines are appearing above and below the widget.

I'd like these dotted lines removed.

To further explain I've made an image at:

http://www.reading-college.ac.uk/sites/default/files/dotted-line-issue.jpg

You can visit my site to see further at:

```
http://www.oxfordlifestylecentre.co.uk/
```

Can anyone advise?

Thanks!

Comment: Why did this get voted down?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please add the below css and check

```
#primary-page-widget-area .widget_mc4wp_widget, #primary-page-widget-area .widget_text {
    border: none !important;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Removing the following style should work:

```
.sidebar-container .widget {
border-bottom: 1px dotted #000000;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Add this line in `/wp-content/themes/designfolio-pro/includes/css/color_schemes/black.css`:

```
.post, .sidebar-container .widget {border: 0;}
```

Or, remove that line from the CSS file.